# EclipseLink includes all fields of entity bean in generated sql

Tags: eclipselink, jpql, weblogic12c

I am using **EclipseLink 2.3.x** with **WebLogic 12c**. 
This is the JQL:

**Select o from PR_GL_CA_ACCOUNT o**

which generated following **error stack**:

<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <>  <2e88ae6781d171fa:-a29df4f:13f38b20f5a:-8000-0000000000000002> <1371045798327>  <2013-06-12 19:03:18.311--UnitOfWork(271275142)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

Internal Exception: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=DISPLAYGLMAPCODE, DRIVER=3.57.82

Error Code: -206

Call: SELECT PCA_GLACCODE, POR_ORGACODE, DISPLAYGLMAPCODE, PCA_FCALLOWED, PCA_GLACACTIVE, PCA_GLACBGTLEVE, PCA_GLACCREATION, PCA_GLACDESC, PCA_GLACDRCRBAL, PCA_GLACEFFECFROM, PCA_GLACEFFECUPTO, PCA_GLACLEVEL, PCA_GLACMAPCODE, PCA_GLACOPITEM, PCA_GLACREVAL, PCA_GLACSBLGR, PCA_GLACSHORT, PCA_GLACTYPE, PCC_ACTGCODE, PCR_CURRCODE, PCT_ACNTCODE, PSH_SCHDCODE, PSY_SYSTCODE FROM PR_GL_CA_ACCOUNT

Query: ReadAllQuery(name="ChartOfAccount.findAllTransactionLevelAccount" referenceClass=ChartOfAccount sql="SELECT PCA_GLACCODE, POR_ORGACODE, DISPLAYGLMAPCODE, PCA_FCALLOWED, PCA_GLACACTIVE, PCA_GLACBGTLEVE, PCA_GLACCREATION, PCA_GLACDESC, PCA_GLACDRCRBAL, PCA_GLACEFFECFROM, PCA_GLACEFFECUPTO, PCA_GLACLEVEL, PCA_GLACMAPCODE, PCA_GLACOPITEM, PCA_GLACREVAL, PCA_GLACSBLGR, PCA_GLACSHORT, PCA_GLACTYPE, PCC_ACTGCODE, PCR_CURRCODE, PCT_ACNTCODE, PSH_SCHDCODE, PSY_SYSTCODE FROM PR_GL_CA_ACCOUNT")> 

####     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <2e88ae6781d171fa:-a29df4f:13f38b20f5a:-8000-0000000000000002> <1371045798561>  weblogic.application.ModuleException: Exception starting module: EJBModule(HelperEJB.jar)



Unable to deploy EJB: ListerInformationDto from HelperEJB.jar:


Singleton ListerInformationDto(Application: EarContent, EJBComponent: HelperEJB.jar) failed to initialize.

    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.start(EJBModule.java:592)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:214)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:36)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:125)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:214)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:36)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:25)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:730)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:36)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:192)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:369)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:52)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:31)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:170)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:124)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:187)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:95)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

Caused By: weblogic.ejb.container.InternalException: Transaction marked rollback or not expected transaction status: 1
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.postCallback(SingletonSessionManager.java:464)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.constructAndInitBean(SingletonSessionManager.java:379)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.access$300(SingletonSessionManager.java:63)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager$SingletonLifecycleManager.doActualInit(SingletonSessionManager.java:798)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager$SingletonLifecycleManager.initInternal(SingletonSessionManager.java:744)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager$SingletonLifecycleManager.init(SingletonSessionManager.java:632)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.init(SingletonSessionManager.java:281)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.SingletonSessionManager.perhapsInit(SingletonSessionManager.java:276)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.initializeBeans(EJBDeployer.java:1280)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.start(EJBDeployer.java:1170)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.start(EJBModule.java:590)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:214)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:36)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:125)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:214)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:36)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:25)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:730)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:36)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:192)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:369)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:52)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:31)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:170)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:124)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:187)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:95)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)



It shows that **DISPLAYGLMAPCODE** is unknown column. After looking at table/code, I found that there is no column in table with same name but there is a private boolean field in entity class with same name without any annotation.


**private boolean displayGLMapCode = false;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to problem is that we need to annotate this field with @Transient.